# Procmail to automatically make new folders to store emails from new senders

Tags: procmail

I am learning how to use procmail but at this point, I am not even sure it's the right tool for what I am trying to do.

So far, I have managed to get fetchmail to retrieve emails from a Google IMAP account and procmail to filter those emails into local folders I had previously created.

I am wondering though whether there is a way to get procmail to automatically create a new folder locally when an email from a new sender is being retrieved and to store that email into that folder.

So far, I have only found a website that describes the possibility of procmail creating automatically folders for mailing lists, but the recipe is something crazy using characters which I have no idea the meaning of, furthermore the official procmail website seems unreachable.

Please can you help? Thank you.

Comment: The Procmail website doesn't host a lot of  documentation; you should be able to find the manual pages on many other sites. Maybe also try http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/quickref.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you expect the folder to be called, and what mailbox format you're using; but assuming maildir folders named by the sender's email terminus, try

```
Who=`formail -rtzxTo:`
:0
* ? mkdir -p "$Who"
$Who/
```

For an mbox folder, you don't need the directory check at all, because the folder is just a single text file, and you'd drop the final slash from the folder name. Mbox needs locking, so add a second colon after the zero.

```
Who=`formail -rtzxTo:`
:0:
$Who
```

Getting `formail` to create a reply and then extracting the `To:` header of the generated reply is a standard but slightly unobvious way to obtain just the email terminus for the sender of the input message.

The shell snippet `mkdir -p dir` creates `dir` if it doesn't already exist, and is a harmless no-op otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @tripleee for your answer.

I expect the folders to be called after the name of each sender. 

Say sender1 and sender2 (with whom I have never had any correspondence before) send emails to my Gmail account. I would like fetchmail to retrieve those emails and procmail to created the folders sender1/ and sender2/ and distribute the emails into those two forlders.

I think the format of my mailboxes is mbox; if that's the case, does your recipe differ?

What do you mean by the terms "email terminus"?

Comment: If you see `From:  Sender McMailface <sender1@example.net>` the email terminus is the machine-readable part `sender1@example.net`

Comment: Updated the answer with an mbox variant.

Comment: You say that in the mbox case I don't need the directory check. Does that mean that even the mkdir command disappears (as you clearly show) and so there is no condition line in this recipe?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Delivery is unconditional.

Comment: The `formail` code is explained in some more detail in my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889697/configure-procmail-to-match-an-external-email-address-list-when-filtering-emails)