# Automatic procmail filter based on username

Tags: procmail

I use postfix and procmail for mail and folder filtering. I have a main address and a bunch of alias addresses that go to it, then I sort the username to a folder that matches. For example I have the main address of 'address@domain.com" and a alias of "customer1@domain.com" pointing to it, and I have a folder called 'customer1' under 'address@domain.com' and a script like the following in .procmailrc -

```
:0:
* ^(To|Cc).*customer1@domain.com 
.customer1/
```

and it works fine, but every time I add a alias I have to also add a line in .procmailrc to filter to it. Would there be a way I can create the alias, the folder, and have one procmail recipe that would grab the 'customer1' from the address and store the message in a folder by that same name? Even having procmail create the folder if it does not exist would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds more like a sysadmin question than a programming question.

Comment: Also, this sounds vaguely like the `Bcc` question: http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#bcc

Comment: @tripleee Almost everything is programming when it comes to Procmail ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found another question that was similar that solved this,
 [Procmail to automatically make new folders to store emails from new senders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512756/procmail-to-automatically-make-new-folders-to-store-emails-from-new-senders?rq=1)

So the following code solved the quesiton -

```
Who=`formail -zxTo: | cut -d@ -f1`
:0
* ? mkdir -p ".$Who"
.$Who/
```

I tested it and it worked wonderfully

Comment: Generally, Procmail can create folders all by its own, no need for `mkdir`.